# Read particular xml node using condition c#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to read particular node in XML like if any "Log"(root node) node contain "Message" node the it should read all the node under the "Log" node.

Note : Log node is root node and there are many node under "log" node.

for Example :

```
<TestLogDataSet>

  <Log>
    <Assembly>TestCase</Assembly>
    <TestMethod>Application</TestMethod>
    <Status>Passed</Status>
    <Trace />
   </Log>


  <Log>
    <Assembly>TestCase</Assembly>
    <TestMethod>Application</TestMethod>
    <Status>Failed</Status>
    <Message>
  <pre><![CDATA[ Error while deleting the Project]]>
 </pre>
    </Message>
    <Trace />

  </Log>

</TestLogDataSet>
```

Code :

```
string xmlFile = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\demo.xml");
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlFile);
foreach (XmlNode lognode in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/TestLogDataSet/Log[Message]"))
{
   foreach (XmlNode node in lognode.ChildNodes)
   {
       string n1 = node.InnerText;
       textBox1.Text = n1 + "\r\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: your code sample is not complete.

Comment: what is missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath for this.

```
StringBuilder nodeText = new StringBuilder();
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(<your xml here>);
foreach (XmlNode lognode in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/TestLogDataSet/Log[Message]")) //select all log nodes with Message as child tag
{
    string status = lognode.SelectSingleNode("./Status").InnerText;
    if (!string.Equals(status,"failed",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
       continue;
    }
    foreach (XmlNode node in lognode.ChildNodes)
    {
         nodeText.Append(node.LocalName);
         nodeText.Append(":");
         nodeText.Append(node.InnerText);//read inner text of node here
         nodeText.Append("\n");
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(nodeText.ToString());
```

Comment: it is taking only last node of xml , if i have more than one Messages node in my xml.

Comment: the code will read all the log nodes which have at least one Message node inside it. Besides i have checked on my end, the code is reading all the message node inside each of log nodes

Comment: ok then how you will print all d child node of LOG node in loop ? here i m using string n1 = node["Status"].InnerText; in second foreach loop but it showing error messsage.

Comment: Check my modfied answer

Comment: that's what i have done but it is not giving correct output..it is not giving all d node value wich have Message node.

Comment: all the node values which have Message node can be obtained in the outer foreach loop. `lognode` is the node which contains message node. inner foreach loop is to read child elements of log node having message node

Comment: when i m wiritng in outer loop it is showing only last Message node and in inner loop it showing error message. can u please tell me where should i print those nodes ?

Comment: you want to print only the Message node's inner text? Right now I am reading all the nodes inside selected Log nodes as asked by you `it should read all the node under the "Log" node`.'

Comment: but it is not reading all the node under "Log" node...it is reading only one Log node if i write print statement in outer loop...

Comment: It will loop through all the nodes. It will pick one node at a time.

Comment: so is it possible to print all the result after getting nodes ?  ( here only  one  node is getting print )

Comment: You can append text of each node to a string and print it outside the foreach loop

Comment: can u please check my code and suggest me where should i print  ? or please modify my code as u told.

Comment: check modified answer

Comment: one more think i want in this is if STATUS node inner text is failed then only MESSAGE node should print..

Comment: same code, but where should i write if statement for Status node inner text ?

Comment: you want only message node?

Comment: i want all the node whose STATUS node inner text is "Failed"

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `Log` nodes then this should suffice:

```
var nodes =
    xd
        .Root
        .Elements("Log")
        .Where(x => x.Element("Message") != null);
```

That gives:

[image: nodes #1]

If you want a list of all of the child nodes (which is what I understand you want from your question, but it seems a bit odd) then this works:

```
var nodes =
    xd
        .Root
        .Elements("Log")
        .Where(x => x.Element("Message") != null)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Elements());
```

This gives:

[image: nodes #2]